# Line passing through $(-1, 3)$ and $(-4, 5)$ in Slope Intercept Form

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Write an equation of the line in slope-intercept form, the line passing through $(-1, 3)$ and $(-4, 5)$. I know that $y=mx + b$ and the slope is $2/3$ but when I plug in the points $3=\frac23 (-1)+b$ to find $b$, I keep getting answers that don't make sense. Graphing hasn't helped either. Just wondering what I am doing wrong.

Comment: You calculated the slope incorrectly.

Answer (score 3):

The slope $m$ is calculated as follows:

$m = (y_2 - y_1) / (x_2 - x_1) = (5 - 3) / (-4 - (-1)) = -2/3$, not $2/3$.

Then you can substitute one of the point's values and $m$ to find $b$.

$y = mx + b$

$5 = -2/3(-4) + b$

$5 = 8/3 + b$

$b = 7/3$

Comment: That is what i kept getting but the teacher said b=5

Comment: @Savannah Then it seems your teacher is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

We know that to find the slope given two points, we use the slope formula which is (y2-y1)/(x2-x1).

Our y2 and y1 are 5 and 3, so the first half of the equation is 5-3. The second half, or x2-x1, is -4-(-1). So our equation to find the slope would be (5-3)/(-4-(-1)) which equals -2/3.

Now that we have our slope, we enter our values in the point-slope formula so we can put the equation in slope-intercept form.

Slope-intercept: Y=Mx+B
Point-slope: y-y1=m(x-x1)

When plugging in our values for y1 and x1, we can use  (-1,3), or (-4,5). It does not matter which one because you will always get the same answer. For this example, we'll use (-1,3).

When we plug in our values, we get:

y-3=-2/3(x-(-1))

**Answer-y=-2/3x+7/3**